# Android/iOS: access users desktop from an app

Tags: android, ios

The situation: An android or iOS user installs a normal app.

Is there ANY way to see the desktop of the user (=which other apps are installed and how the icons are arranged) from the apps perspective?

I did not find an easy solution to this. Is there any trick like making the app transparent for a second and doing a screenshot and then OCRing the desktop etc that might work?

The user is on our side / will give any permissions that are necessary. Complex/expensive to build solutions are fine, it can be something that takes a couple months to build.

Comment: Could you ask the user to take screenshots of all their pages? On iOS you can programmatically get all the recent screenshots and from there OCR the image. Not sure about on android though.

Comment: That's basically a valid idea, thanks! Still, too much work by the user required this way.

Comment: Do you have control over the devices (ie, rootable or jailbreakable?) because I know there are some iOS tweaks that pull images of springboard.

Comment: no - unfortunately. We assume random consumer devices with a popular mainstream ad. Again good idea.